# Pyarrow is slower than pandas for csv read in

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I am trying to open some csv files with python 3.9. I was puzzled by timing pandas vs pyarrow :

[image]

Is it normal that pyarrow takes that much time? I thought that it was commonly agreed that it should be much faster. These csv files have not been created using pandas and their size is about 5GB (they come from the Twitter API). What could be the reasons that lead to this result?

Comment: you may want to compare `df1.dtypes` with `df_2.schema` as it may be the case that pandas does a better job at figuring out the underlying type of columns and using efficient native types (eg: datetime, floats etc instead of string)

Comment: Can you upload a small sample file and create a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/login.jsp)?

Comment: By any chance, are you using a macbook m1 ? i had a very similiar issue on m1 mackbooks with the wrong version of python installed. 
If you are using a Macbook M1 please make sure that you have an arm64 version of python installed. you can check using print(f"Python version: {python_version()}, Machine: {machine()}")

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am using a MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021). when I print what you've suggested I get the following:
Python version: 3.9.10, Machine: x86_64
Do I need to reinstall python?

Comment: Yes python and your project dependencies ! make sure it prints "arm64" for the machine. This should fix it for you. (it did for me) 

pyarrow was clealy going through Rosetta which explains the latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyarrow and Macbook Silicon

If you are using a Mac computer with Apple Silicon, please make sure that you are using the `arm64` version of python and not `x86_64`.